Consulta de suma simultaneas
Tengo una tabla que la nombré "mercaderia" en ella tengo columnas de las cuales quiero hacer 2 consultas simultáneamente una en cada columna, una de ellas ya la hice que es la del filtro que muestra el último registro de la columna "precio_venta" por cada código. La otra consulta es: quiero sumar la columna "pack" agrupado por código es decir un código tiene varios registros con diferentes valores en la col. "pack" y quiero sumar todos para que me arroje un total por cada código. ya lo hice con HAVING y no está sumando (ojo las 2 consultas tiene que visualizarse simultáneamente en una tabla y tiene que ser independientes es decir la suma tiene que procesar los datos de la tabla original (no alterada por la consulta de filtro)
SELECT a.codigo, a.fecha, a.precio_venta, SUM(pack) stock
FROM mercaderia as a
INNER JOIN ( SELECT codigo, MAX(fecha) fecha_max
            FROM mercaderia
            where pack>0
            GROUP BY codigo) b
            ON a.codigo = b.codigo
            AND a.fecha = b.fecha_max
GROUP BY codigo
HAVING SUM(pack)

Intenté con HAVING pero no está sumando. Gracias de antemano...

Cómo podemos ayudarte con una query cuando no conocemos la base de datos ni los datos que contiene??? Pásanos una definición de la tabla, datos de prueba para rellenarla y un ejemplo de salida correcta.

Estoy prácticamente segura de que esa no es la sintaxis de HAVING, por cierto. Está bueno pasearse por la documentación de vez en cuando.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gDQnkEaqtXmMwnyO4jem9D0cX6JVv5Mb/view?usp=sharing                                                                                                                     listo ahi les dejo la tabla, no son datos reales, solo es una de prueba                   bueno la idea es que sume todos los valore de la columna pack por codigo, un codigo dara un resultado, el segundo codigo dará otro resultado y asi sucesivamente, estos resultados son el stock de mercaderia que tengo a disposicion en el dia (es decir el stock actual)............ se agradece de antemano

Los datos de ejemplo deben estar presentes siempre en la pregunta misma, no a través de enlaces externos. Si el enlace cae, parte relevante de la pregunta se perderá. Es por eso que se pide un [repro] (énfasis en mínimo).

ok pero no se como subir tablas en esta pagina web :( me explicas como se hace lo de subir tablas por favor? necesito terminar este proyecto para el fds ...

Hola buenas tardes se te olvido poner a.pack en el apartado SUM(a.pack), HAVING SUM(a.pack) y GROUP BY a.codigo, también no se si stock existe en la tabla si existe se te olvido poner ,a.stock o si es un nombre que quieres darle a SUM(a.pack) se te olvido poner as delante de stock

hola gracias por tu interes pero ya lo resolvi
